# When converting UILabel to NSString, NSString automatically makes value '0'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uilabel

I am working on a calculator app and the "equals" button just does not want to work.

When a user enters in a number and presses the "multiply" button what ever is currently on the `UILabel` gets converted to an integer, then stored in an `NSInteger`. When the user begins entering the next set of numbers, the label gets switched to whatever they type in.

When the user presses "equals", what is supposed to happen is the current `UILabel` gets converted to an `NSString`, then to `NSInteger` and multiplied by the previously stored result. Then that new integer is converted to an `NSString` and set to the `UILabel`.

The problem is that when the code sets the label to a string, it automatically changes everything to a 0. Now I don't know if the `UILabel` is simply not going to an `NSString`, or when setting an `NSString` to the contents of a `UILabel` is not picking up an content from the `UILabel`.

Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)equalsWhenPressed:(id)sender {

    if ([operation  isEqual:@"x"]) {

        //get the UILabels text
        NSString *flabb = self.screen.text;

        //converting the string to a integer
        NSInteger yahh = [flabb integerValue];

        //doing the multiplication
        NSInteger actualProblem = yahh * storedResult;

        NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)actualProblem];

        self.screen.text = result;

       operation = nil;
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "changes everything to 0"? Clearly tell us what is wrong with the code you posted. What is the value of `flabb`? What is the value of `storedResult`?

Comment: So you are saying the converted value from the string (yahh) is equal to zero always?

Comment: storedResult is whatever the user enters before hitting times. And that saves and inputs fine. The problem is that the flabb outputs 0. When i set the screen to flabb i was trying something and forgot to remove it. I fixed the code. Thank you.

Comment: @DylanCrocker no, the value of flabb is always equal to zero when it is not supposed to be.

Comment: flabb is just a pointer to the text on screen so how can it be zero if the label text isn't zero? Are you correctly accessing the text in the label?

Comment: @DylanCrocker That is my problem. I may be doing it wrong, but from what I understand Im doing it right. I only have this problem here -- No where else.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the actual value of flabb with the debugger or NSLog?

Comment: @Chuck yes, I have tried NSLogging it and have done some other tests to confirm that flab is making everything equal zero

Comment: You're still not saying what you mean by "changes everything to 0". What is "everything"?

Comment: Have you logged self.screen to make sure it's not nil?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well lets look at your code:

```
//get the UILabels text
NSString *flabb = self.screen.text; // <-- This effectually does nothing  

//converting the string to a integer
NSInteger yahh = [flabb integerValue];
```

The first line does nothing but declare a pointer to the label's text in memory. You could have just as easily wrote:

```
NSInteger yahh = [self.screen.text integerValue];
```

Not to pick at your code mind you but I think the point is relevant. Now, if the text you have entered in the Label is not output by NSLog here:

```
//get the UILabels text
NSString *flabb = self.screen.text; // <-- This effectually does nothing 

NSLog(@"%@", flabb); // <-- This is directly printing what is in the UILabel "screen".    
NSLog(@"%@", self.screen.text); // This will be the same.

//converting the string to a integer
NSInteger yahh = [flabb integerValue];
```

Then you are accessing the text wrong (e.g. the label you think you are typing into is not named "screen", etc).

I have this running in an app right now:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
label.text = @"1";
NSLog(@"%i", [label.text intValue]);
```

It prints one just fine. Please check your code to make sure you are accessing the UILabel text correctly.

Here is a test for you to try (in your original method):

```
if (self.screen != nil)
{
  //get the UILabels text
  NSString *flabb = self.screen.text; // <-- This effectually does nothing 

  NSLog(@"%@", flabb); // <-- This is directly printing what is in the UILabel "screen".    
  NSLog(@"%@", self.screen.text); // This will be the same.

  //converting the string to a integer
  NSInteger yahh = [flabb integerValue];

  // Rest of your code here...
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"%@",@"screen is nil!");
}
```

Now if any of your other code starts running then "screen" is not nil and is correctly pointing to a UILabel. Otherwise the handle to your label is not connected to the IBOutlet! If that's the case then its an easy fix.

Note: double check the spelling of your UILabel ("screen", or "Screen", etc).

Comment: Im pretty sure I'm accessing UIlabel text correctly. I only have this problem in this particular situation. no where else.

Comment: Well then you must post some more code, because the issue isn't in what was posted. You said the string flabb is nil (0 pointer) or @"0"?

Comment: I just put the full .m file in the question. Again, from what I understand from NSLogging flabb is outputting @"0" when it shouldn't be.

Comment: I added some more information to my answer. Hope it helps you understand what is happening at a more fundamental level. Please consider up-voting the comments/answers from the people trying to help you. Thanks.

Comment: I really thank you for this, unfortunately because I'm new to stack overflow i cannot rate anything up. I would love to settle this answered but nothing is working for me. I will try again tomorrow and maybe re-write a few things. Again, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add the line below to your code and tell us what you are getting in the output window?
Your code looks corrects unless the string is not a numeric and intValue will return 0 on conversion (it will not trigger an exception)

```
//get the UILabels text
NSString *flabb = self.screen.text;

// add this line
NSLog(@"flabb == %@" , flabb );

//converting the string to a integer
NSInteger yahh = [flabb integerValue];
```